# Group Pandas dataframe Age column by Age groups

Tags: pandas, mapping, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 10,000 ages that I want to group by these groups

```
def age1(x): 
    if x < 30: return '18-29' 
    elif x < 40: return '30-39' 
    elif x < 50: return '40-49' 
    elif x < 60: return '50-59'
    elif x < 70: return '60-69' 
    elif x >=70: return '70+' 
    else: return 'other'
```

I tried an For loop and a lambda function:

```
map(lambda x : "18-29" if (x >= 18) and (x < 30) else "other",[1,10,20,30])
```

but nothing runs!

I am having trouble and getting many errors like these:
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

My dataframe consists of two columns I pulled from my main dataframe and looks like this:

```
    Age Exited
0   42  1
1   41  0
2   42  1
3   39  0
4   43  0
```

What I want is another column Entitled "Ages by Group" so what is the most efficient way to perform this?

Comment: Use `pd.cut` or your function like `df['new'] = df['Age'].apply(age1)`

Comment: Thank you as that worked well: 
bins = [ 18, 25, 35, 50, 70, 90]
mainDf['GroupedbyAge'] = pd.cut(mainDf['Age'], bins)
mainDf.head(12)